# UIButton in UINavigationBar layout mystery

Tags: ios, uibutton, uikit, uinavigationbar

So our custom nav bar (subclassed from `UINavigationBar`) is set to a larger custom height of 64 (via overriding `sizeThatFits`).  One of the reasons we do this is that we use a square icon as the navbar's `titleView` (see the code below).  The problem is that the nav layout strangely places it so that it overhangs the nav bar, no matter how I seem to play with setting the button's frame (see pic):

In my `UITableViewController`, this code is in `viewWillAppear`:

```
    CGRect navFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

    {
        UIImage* buttonImage = _menu.icon;
        //UIImage* buttonImage = [_menu.icon resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];

        UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

        [[button imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
        [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, navFrame.size.height, navFrame.size.height);

        self.navigationItem.titleView = button;

    }
```

Strangely, if I increase the size of our navbar's custom height from 64 to, say, 84, nav buttons all move down 20, including the `titleView`, causing it to overhang by the same distance.  In other words, it's not clear why layout is happening this way or what the best solution might be.

Any help dispelling the PFM of `UINavigationBar` would be appreciated!